# How to create a floating search view on android with google maps as the background?

Tags: java, android, maps

so i am currently trying to develop and app that needs to integrate google maps on the home page, so i was wondering how to add a floating search view on that home page

Answer (score 1):

This might serve your purpose, [Link](https://github.com/codecameo/PlaceAutoCompleteSearch)